# What target triple should I use to build a Rust project for an AWS Graviton2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rust, arm, cross-compiling

I would like to cross compile Rust code on my amd64 host system to run on an [AWS Graviton2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/graviton/) instance.

Based on [Getting started with C/C++ on Graviton guide](https://github.com/aws/aws-graviton-getting-started/blob/master/c-c%2B%2B.md), it seems like I want something like `armv8`. The only such triples [in the list of Rust's supported target triples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html) start with `thumbv8m`. I don't know anything about ARM, so not sure if these are what I want, and if so, which one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct target will be `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`. You could also perform Arm-native compilation on the AWS Graviton2 instance.

Comment: Using `cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release`, I am getting a linker error on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/greg/code/2021/auth_service/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/authrs-2bcc83ab19d2eb0d.authrs.azs2f3xv-cgu.0.rcgu.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas? I'm guessing that any one building for AWS's T4g (Rust-based) servers will have this problem.

Comment: to answer my own questions, it is easier (and probably better) to use https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross. An example `cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-musl --release`